# CSS/JS switch thumbnail opacity for simple product gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, thumbnails

I am building a very simple product gallery, just 2 thumbnails with 1 enlargement to  show/front back of a product. I have got the image switch working and opacity on the thumbnail, on hover, please see code pen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGeBWB  (for some reason the code-pen does not switch images, it works fine locally, but it still illustrates the issue).

```
.button:hover {  opacity:0.8  }

function switchImg(i) {
   document.images["wine"].src = i;
}
```

All I want is the thumbnails to swap opacity, so when the thumbnail is clicked, it gets the opacity to indicate its accompanying big image is being displayed and visa versa, if anyone wants to put some CSS ease-in effects/fades etc then that would also help.

Comment: `document.images["wine"].src = 'http://bonrouge.com/' + i` you must include the full path.

Comment: The code pen works a bit better but does not solve the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your console output (Failed to load the resource). You have an 406 data error - server is not allowing access to the file. Check the file permissions of the image on your server (should at least be 644) and that you have MOD permissions set to allow remote image requests.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the changes below. The issues are :

- You need to mention the full image path while calling the function.
- It is better to use the `document.getElementById` while pointing an dom element exclusively.

```js
function switchImg(i) {
  document.getElementById("imageSRC").src = i;
}
```

```css
.button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8
}
```

```html
<img id="imageSRC" src="http://bonrouge.com/wine.jpg" id="wine" height="500" width="300" alt="">

<a href="#" onClick="switchImg('http://bonrouge.com/wine.jpg')" class="button">
  <img src="http://bonrouge.com/wine.jpg" height="100" width="100" alt=""></a>

<a href="#" onClick="switchImg('http://bonrouge.com/beer.jpg')" class="button">
  <img src="http://bonrouge.com/beer.jpg" height="100" width="100" alt=""></a>
```

Code Pen : http://codepen.io/kishoresahas/pen/epbjRm